# Handle exceptions thrown by nested promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird

I don't understand why my application throws an unhandled exception or how I could avoid this. The exception is thrown on the `reject(new Error('...'))` line

**The function which throws the exception:**

```
function parseSourceStrings(fileInformation, callback) {
    var filePath = fileInformation.path
    var fileExtension = path.extname(filePath)
    switch(fileExtension) {
        case '.pot':
        case '.po':
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                poProcessor.processFile(filePath).then(function(result) {
                    result = addMetaData(fileInformation, result)
                    resolve(result)
                }).catch(function(err) {
                    reject(err)
                })
            })
        default:
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                reject(new Error('Unknwown file format'))
            })
    }
}
```

**This is how I call the function:**

```
mv(filePath, targetFilePath, {mkdirp: true}).then(function() {
    return uploadHandler.parseSourceStrings(fileInformation)
}).then(function(parsedSourceStrings) {
    console.log(parsedSourceStrings)
}).catch(function(err) {
    logger.error(err)
    next(err)
})
```

**The thrown exception:**

```
2:50:19 AM - error: Error: Unknwown file format
    at result.meta_information (c:\Users\h9pe\Documents\tms-reworked\app\projects\process-uploads\upload-handler.js:34:12)
    at Object.parseSourceStrings (c:\Users\h9pe\Documents\tms-reworked\app\projects\process-uploads\upload-handler.js:33:11)
    at c:\Users\h9pe\Documents\tms-reworked\app\projects\router.js:117:26
    at tryCatcher (c:\Users\h9pe\Documents\tms-reworked\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Promise.module.exports.Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (c:\Users\h9pe\Documents\tms-reworked\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise.module.exports.Promise._settlePromise (c:\Users\h9pe\Documents\tms-reworked\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise.module.exports.Promise._settlePromise0 (c:\Users\h9pe\Documents\tms-reworked\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise.module.exports.Promise._settlePromises (c:\Users\h9pe\Documents\tms-reworked\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
    at Promise.module.exports.Promise._fulfill (c:\Users\h9pe\Documents\tms-reworked\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:638:18)
    at module.exports (c:\Users\h9pe\Documents\tms-reworked\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\nodeback.js:42:21)
    at c:\Users\h9pe\Documents\tms-reworked\node_modules\mv\index.js:34:26
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15) '/projects/13/update/sourcestrings'
```

Apparently it's simply an unhandled exception, but the catch was supposed to catch thrown exceptions no? How would I properly catch the exceptions?

Comment: FYI, you can replace you second `reject()` line with `return Promise.reject(new Error(...));`  Much shorter and to the point.  Not sure why you get an error on the original line there.

Comment: are you sure that is an unhandled error and not just the output of `logger.error(err)`

Comment: Your exception is because your `parseSourceStrings()` function is hitting the default line in the switch statement and thus returning a reject promise.  Your call to `uploadHandler.parseSourceStrings(fileInformation)` then rejects which causes you to hit your `.catch()` and you see the error logged.  That appears to be working as coded, though perhaps your code is getting an unexpected file extension.

Comment: FYI - avoid the promise constructor anti-pattern - your function could be simplified to https://jsfiddle.net/65c9bgxh/

Comment: @JaromandaX X Thanks for the jsfiddle, so bluebird rejects catched exceptions by default since you've ommited this?

Comment: @jfriend00 indeed I was expecting to hit the default line, I've uploaded a file with an unknown format on purpose. However I expected it to be caught, but that was not the case. However with the improvements suggested by you guys it doesn't happen anymore anyways. I am very thankful for these "offtopic" tips, they will help me a lot.

Comment: No, I omitted the catch because I wouldn't even put `.catch(function(err) {
                    reject(err)
                })` inside a Promise constructor, ever ... it goes nowhere, doesn nothing, *I'm going to handle this error by throwing this error*

Comment: @kentor, your code: `new Promise((resolve.reject) => something().catch(err) => reject(err))` is the promise equivalent of `try { something(); }catch(err){ throw err }` immediately re-throwing the catched error. That's why this particular `catch()` is obsolete.